# Проблемы с выделением строк в таблице SQlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Пытаюсь выделить все строки таблицы. Но выделяется почему-то только первая вставленная. Вот мой код. Помогите найти проблему.

**Код:**

```
package com.example;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Ruler{
    public static Statement statmt4;
    private static ResultSet resset2;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            conn = null;
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:IdChangedDB.s3db");
            statmt4 = conn.createStatement();
            statmt4.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists 'IdChangedDB' ('id' text, 'latitude' text, 'longitude' text, 'distancefortb' text);");
            statmt4.execute("INSERT INTO 'IdChangedDB' ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'distancefortb') VALUES (' 1 ', ' 51.6666 ', ' 54.677789 ', ' c ');");
            statmt4.execute("INSERT INTO 'IdChangedDB' ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'distancefortb') VALUES (' 2 ', ' 52.6666 ', ' 55.677789 ', ' d ');");
            statmt4.execute("INSERT INTO 'IdChangedDB' ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'distancefortb') VALUES (' 3 ', ' 53.6666 ', ' 56.677789 ', ' e ');");
            resset2 = statmt4.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM IdChangedDB;");
            System.out.print(resset2.getString("id"));
            System.out.print(resset2.getString("latitude"));
            System.out.print(resset2.getString("longitude"));
            System.out.print(resset2.getString("distancefortb"));

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

**P.S.**
Я не очень понимаю, почему тогда столько мануалов в гугле, которые как-бы свидетельствуют о работоспособности. Гуглу нельзя верить?
Примеры: [тыц](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/mysql/select-allrecords.html) и [тыц](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/Selectingallrowsfromatableandcreatesaresultset.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(reset2.next())
  System.out.println(resset2.getString("id")
       + " " + resset2.getString("latitude")...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте, так, либо пройдитесь циклом

```
rs.first(); 

System.out.print(resset2.getString("id"));
System.out.print(resset2.getString("latitude"));
System.out.print(resset2.getString("longitude"));
System.out.print(resset2.getString("distancefortb"));

resset2.next();

System.out.print(resset2.getString("id"));
System.out.print(resset2.getString("latitude"));
System.out.print(resset2.getString("longitude"));
System.out.print(resset2.getString("distancefortb"));
```

---

```
while (resset2.next()) {
    System.out.print(resset2.getString("id"));
    System.out.print(resset2.getString("latitude"));
    System.out.print(resset2.getString("longitude"));
    System.out.print(resset2.getString("distancefortb"));
}
```

Comment: Фигня. Выдает  1  51.6666  54.677789  c  1  51.6666  54.677789  c. До этого выдавало просто 1  51.6666  54.677789  c. А с resset2.first(); выдает ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.

Comment: @DenShDen т.е. получается что у вас и в первой и во второй строке лежат одни и теже данные?

Comment: в этом и прикол, что лежит-то все нормально.
Удаляю дб. Запускаю. Инсертятся вон те значения (тобишь 3 строки добавляются).
А дальше какого-то фига мне выводится только первая добавленная.
P.S. Сработал нижний ответ.